# Cannot create custom fields with the wpapi Node.js wrapper for WordPress REST

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, rest, api

I use the following snippet to create a WordPress post via the REST API, using the Node.js wrapper:

```
   var wp = new WPAPI({
       endpoint: 'http://your-site.com/wp-json',
       username: 'someusername',
       password: 'password'
   });
   wp.posts().create({
       title: 'Your Post Title',
       content: 'Your post content',
       status: 'publish',
       meta: { "custom_field": "my custom field value" }
   }).then(function( response ) {
       console.log( response.id );
   })
```

When fetching the posts, the `meta` is empty.

Why is that and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason that did not work for me either. I ended by using a WordPress REST hook.

In `functions.php` I added:

```
add_filter( 'pre_post_update' , function ( $post_id , $post ) {
  $body = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
  $meta_fields = $body["meta"];
  foreach ($meta_fields as $meta_key => $value) {
      update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $value);
  }
}, '99', 2 );
```

The snippet above will parse the `meta` field and will update the post metadata fields.

If you want to include the custom fields in the responses, you can use:

```
//Get custom fields via Rest API
add_action( 'rest_pre_echo_response', function( $response, $object, $request ) {
  //* Get the post ID
  $post_id = $response[ 'id' ];
  if ($response['type'] !== 'post' && $response['type'] !== 'page') return $response;
  $response['custom_fields'] = get_post_meta($post_id);
  return $response;
}, 10, 3 );
```